# output a variable onclick

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm a beginner about javascript, and I have some doubts about the variables of this language.

For example, I have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Prova_Index</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function stampa(){
var Name = document.name.utente.value;
document.Write(Name);
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="name">
<p> Write some text:</p>
<input type="text" id="utente">

</form>
<input type="submit" value="Click me" onClick="stampa()"> 
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code, my doubts is specialy how save the values of the textbox with the id 'utente'.

Comment: Please do not put "help", "urgent" or similar phrases in the question title. Please edit your question to a) use a meaningful title, b) explain exactly what you are trying to do. Right now it's not really clear what you want. How do you want to "save" the value?

Comment: [Learn more about the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM): [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write this code by replacing your code

```
function stampa()
            {
                var Name = document.getElementById('utente').value;
                alert(Name);
                return false;
            }
    <input type="text" id="utente">

    <input type="submit" value="Click me" onclick="return stampa();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var Name = document.name.utente.value;`, you probably want to use something like `var Name = document.getElementById('utente').value;`

Really, you might want to consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead.  It's far more reliable for cross-browser oddities than using plain old DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

This Javascript should store the value of that input element into the variable 'Name' and then write it out.

```
var Name = document.getElementById("utente").value;

document.write(Name);
```

I will forewarn you that when you use HTML `<form>` tags and try to execute a function using a `submit` input, the page will submit and then the onClick function will not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Please explain us what you want to do. It isn't clear to us.

Second of all. I recommend using ID's when you are beginning with JavaScript programming.

When you take a look at your code. It will submit after the function is ready. So you can try and use this:

```
<input type="submit" value="click me" onclick="stampa( ); return false;" />
```

It won't submit the form and you can see your result.
You can also use an alert( ); function for debugging or console.log( ); if you use Firefox with Firebug or Opera with Dragonfly.

You can try this in your script:

```
console.log( document.getElementById( 'something' ).value( ) );
```